# Storing Array values in Excel file using Perl

Tags: regex, excel, perl

How to store array values in Excel using Perl ?

**Example:**

```perl
@animals = ("Cat", "Dog", "Horse");
@fruits = ("Mango", "Apple", "Orange");
```

**Output:**  In Excel file

```
Animals Fruits
Cat     Mango
Dog     Apple
Horse   Orange
```

Comment: Please show the code you gave already written to try this.

Comment: @JGNI I dont have any code...I m having only idea like this...I want the expected output in excel format

Comment: @zdim Do you have any  idea about this question??

Comment: What do you mean by "Excel file"? Does it need to be `.xlsx`, or can it be any file that Excel can read? I mean, producing some output in the right format is pretty simple. But writing it to a `.xlsx` file adds a whole other level of complexity.

Comment: A minimum `Excel` file could be a csv file, produced from `Text::CSV`

Comment: @ Dave Cross I need that output to be in .xlsx file format

Comment: If CSV is not acceptable as input format, then you'll need to use [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX). IMHO that is only required if you *must* also set formatting, etc. information for cells. If you just need to have a table that Excel is able to import, then CSV is enough.

Comment: @DaveCross I want my output file to be in .xlsx format.I saw your answers and I got more information from the documentation which you have provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 would be to take your input data and convert it into the rows and columns that you want.

```
my @output = map { [ $animals[$_], $fruits[$_] ] } 0 .. $#animals;
```

Step 2 would be to put that in an Excel file. A simple CSV file is really easy.

```
open my $fh, '>', 'mydata.csv' or die $!;

say join ',', @$_ for @output;
```

An `.xlsx` is harder.

```
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'perl.xlsx' );
$worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

for my $col (0 .. 1) {
  for my $row (0 .. $#animals) {
    $worksheet->write($row, $col, $output[$row, $col]);
  }
}

$workbook->close();
```

More details in the documentation for [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX).

Answer (score 2):

Example code that generates CSV format with [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) which is an accepted input format for Excel. As long as no formatting, type, etc. are required there is no need to generate `.xlsx` format.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV;

my @animals = ("Cat", "Dog", "Horse");
my @fruits  = ("Mango", "Apple", "Orange");

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    binary   => 1,
    eol      => "\n",
    sep_char => ',', # default
}) or die "CSV\n";

$csv->print(\*STDOUT, [qw(Animals Fruits)]);
foreach my $i (0..$#animals) {
    $csv->print(\*STDOUT, [ $animals[$i], $fruits[$i] ]);
}

exit 0;
```

Test output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
Animals,Fruits
Cat,Mango
Dog,Apple
Horse,Orange
```